# How to check a message string against an array

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

In discord.js I have created a bot.
I'm attempting to check a message with an array of strings.
The code I have an issue with looks like this:

```
module.exports = (client, message) => {
  var mcheck = message.content;
  for (i in mcheck) {
    var checkList = ['tomato', 'green']
    var inMSG = message.content.split(' ')
    var check = inMSG.includes(checkList[0, 1])
    if (check == true) {
      message.reply('This message included green or tomato!')
    }
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is that `message` in the second line is unrecognized.

Comment: There is an syntax error at your code. Please fix this first.

Answer (score 2):

The lines of code with :

`for (i in mcheck) {`

and

`var check = inMSG.includes(checkList[0,1])`

are probably the lines that are flagged as invalid.

I am assuming `mcheck` is an array. If you are trying to iterate through an array, it is better to use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), or the classic [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) statement.

```
for (let i = 0; i < mcheck.length; i++) {
  ...
}
```

Also, this is what you can do instead in order to check if the `message` string contains any of the words within the `checkList` array:

```js
const str = 'There is green or tomato';
const checkList = ['green','tomato']

checkList.some(substring => str.includes(substring));
```